# Pole Light keeps tripping Breaker

Tags: light, post

I have a post light that I replaced. The old post rusted out at the bottom and fell over. So I dug a new hole and set in a new post and fixture. Before this, I tested the breaker with a generic light for a few hours running on the ground wired in. No problems with the breaker. I installed the new post light with a photocell light sensor. It was working great until my son poked in the hole covering I had on the post. It rained the next day pretty heavily. From that point on, the breaker keeps tripping. I replaced the photocell thinking it had gotten moisture in it and still, the breaker keeps tripping. The breaker is only a 15 amp break. The post light is the only thing on this breaker. Any ideas as to why the breaker keeps tripping? Do I need a 20amp breaker or is something else going on? Is the photocell causing the breaker to trip?

Comment: Does the breaker have a TEST button on it?  The cable that was run out to the light, what kind is it?

Comment: I would also want to inspect the wiring if the wiring was skinned it might work fine while dry but when the ground got wet now there could be a current path that would trip a standard breaker.

Comment: It is 14 gauge wire. I will know tomorrow if I fixed it for sure. I took everything appart, cleaned everything with electrical cleaner and redid every connection. The grounding wire was loose when I removed it. Probably from shoving the sensor down the pipe.

Comment: @JoeWarner -- is there a paper separator between the plastic jacket and the individual wires in the cable?

Comment: Light still popped the breaker. Stays on for about an hour I am guessing. Could it be that when I am shoving everything back it, the connections get loose or the is a nick somewhere in the wire? The wire is direct burial so there is no way to tell if it is damaged underground...and I am not tearing up my front yard to find out.

Comment: @JoeWarner can you get access to an insulation resistance meter/"megger"?

Answer (score 1):

A typical residential pole light should be at most a few hundred watts (which would be a few amperes of current), and typically far less, even with incandescent bulbs. With compact fluorescent or LEDs then even less. So if you are tripping the breaker due to too much current (> 15 A) then upgrading to a 20 A breaker would not be a good idea as the 15 A breaker is actually protecting you, the device, your wiring and your house properly. If you ever had a good reason to upgrade to 20 A (e.g., if the wiring was to also serve an outdoor receptacle for plugging in tools) then you would need to first make sure that the wiring is suitable for a 20 A circuit (typically this means 12 AWG instead of 14 AWG).

A more likely explanation than overcurrent is a GFCI trip. That is what Harper is referring to with "Does the breaker have a TEST button on it?" A GFCI is designed to protect you from **ground faults**. A ground fault can be caused by a number of issues, and moisture is definitely one of them. A photocell (or other circuit devices such as timers, dimmers, smart switches) functioning properly will not trigger GFCI trips. However, moisture on the wiring (bulb socket, photocell connections or any other wiring in the circuit) can cause a ground fault and trip the GFCI. **That is what it is designed to do.**

A GFCI is typically installed either together with an outlet or as part of the breaker installed in the panel. So look at the panel first. If the breaker has a "TEST" button then it most likely has GFCI protection (which is recommended for outside circuits, and generally required by code for new outside circuits) and you need to fix the problem, not replace the breaker. If the breaker does not include GFCI protection then check all outlets that are on the same circuit - you will likely find one that has GFCI protection with the light fed from the **load** terminals. However, my bet is on a GFCI breaker because if the GFCI were downstream then the breaker would not trip because the GFCI would trip first.

Fixing the problem will involve taking apart the light and getting it totally dry and reinstalling it and **make sure that all holes where water can enter are properly covered** so that the problem doesn't happen again.

Comment: I am very familiar with GFCI's.  I can find out wire size when I get home this afternoon and take apart the pole light again. If it is moisture, how do I protect my wire nuts?

Comment: There are wire nuts available that have a sealant in them and a little boot-like cover, specifically for using outdoors. They are a lot more expensive, but worth it. If you want to test the theory, spray some WD-40 on the connections and see if the breaker holds. If it does, that's where the problem lies. If not, it's a problem somewhere else, like a nick in a wire.